# How to simulate "force refresh" like when you hit enter at address bar in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, routes, refresh, single-page-application

I notice that clicking the refresh button is different than hitting enter at the address bar.

I am now working on a SPA, where using `window.location.reload()` does not return to the index page (whose url is same as the current page). Yet when hit enter at the address bar, the site will jump back to the index page.

How to simulate that kind of refresh - utter refresh when you do it at the location bar - in JavaScript?

Comment: Have you tried `window.location.reload(true)`? This sets `skipCache` to true and will reload the page from the server.

Comment: Yes and it is not working.